# Multiple Google Analytics Tracking IDs in Single Page?

Tags: google-analytics

We are creating a site that deals with multiple users, each with their own 'white label' portal that is accessed by a unique sub-domain URL. We want to maintain our own tracking metrics through Google analytics but also wish to provide the white label users the option of using their own tracking ID for their unique sub-domain.

My question is this: Is it possible (or even supported) to have multiple Tracking ID code snippets on a single page in a web site?

Comment: Yes. It is supported and possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Docs has information on this at [One Push, Multiple Commands](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html#MultipleCommands):

```
_gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
    ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-2'],
    ['b._trackPageview']
);
```

Comment: Why there's a "b."? What is that for?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo b. is the second tracker for the other profile. It has to be distinguished from the other account.

Comment: Thanks, so it just can be anything, right? I tried the way without adding a 'b.' it still works.. weird.