# How can we use more than one Google Analytics tracking Id in Google Analytics for Firebase in android and ios

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics

In previous we used Google Analytic SDK with GA Tracking ID for tracking event and activity in mobile application. We could use more than one GA Tracking Id in application. but right now Google Analytic is using with Firebase that known as `Google Analytics for Firebase` that's link is [Google Analytics for Firebase.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en) Now I want to know that how we can use more than two GA tracking ID using `Google Analytics for Firebase`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Google Analytics Tracking IDs in Single Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384654/multiple-google-analytics-tracking-ids-in-single-page)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GTM + Firebase implementation. Adding GTM as a control layer before sending data to GA allow you to a lot of things a have control without the need of updating the app.

[iOS Docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/)

[Android Docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/)

Hope it helps !

--EDIT:

Maybe i forgot to mention that adding GTM easily allows you to duplicate the hits to two (or more) different GA account.

Comment: thanks for the replay. As of February 2022, do you know how to do that?